# iOS device FT232R USB chip not supported

Tags: ios, iphone, iokit

I'm developing an iOS app that would communicate to FT232R USB chip using serial ports. iOS device, it shows error "Connected device is not supported" on connection. Couldn't get any benefit after jail breaking too. I need it for internal project and dont want to upload it on Apple store. Using IOKit (private framework) for communication to serial port.

Comment: You'll get that message for anything that's neither one of the standard supported USB device types (camera, storage, keyboard, audio), nor MFI-compliant. Have you tried anything with the USB bits of the IOKit Framework regardless? Another option might be to use a Bluetooth LE based RS232 adapter.

Comment: Is it required after jailbreak also?

Comment: I don't know, at least some versions back you didn't need a JB for using IOKit. Not sure what it's like now or for USB specifically